# Creak in frame best practice?

Tags: creak

Has anyone troubleshooted a creak issue by  leaning the bike at an angle and pushing down at the crank at about a 6 o clock position , causing the bottom frame to kind of flex to listen for any type of creaks?.... Is this a normal method of troubleshooting because I was pissed when I saw this done to my bike.

Comment: I've seen that sort of test done.  It's a reasonable procedure, when trying to narrow down a creak.  (Consider the stresses placed on the crank and frame when you stand and pedal hard.)

Comment: Yeah, its about as reasonable procedure as any. Creaks in bikes are hard to find, since tubes carry sound. But the first thing I check for is physical damage first (e.g. cracks).

Comment: Ok thank you .That's good to know. Come to find out the cause of the creak was  kind of odd. After more troubleshooting I noticed the creak was coming from the seat, after cleaning and re fiber pasting the seatpost, torqued to spec seat  and readjusting the seat rails the noise was gone for about 30 min! Looking again at the issue I noticed the seat post was lower than normal I moved the seat post up a bit to the second indication line on the steam and retorqued and oddly the sound has been gone for about a day. I wouldn't think a seatpost height would cause a creak?

Comment: A slipping seatpost can cause a creak. So can the saddle rails. I'd take it apart, clean everything, and then re-install it.

Comment: I had a seatpost creak that turned out to be a crack in the frame under the clamp.   Creaks are hard.

Comment: Why were you pissed? If you think that puts a lot of force on the frame, imagine what riding up a steep hill at speed will do.

Comment: @Criggie - Yeah, unfortunately a crack can leave you up the creek if it leads to failure at an inconvenient time.

Comment: Update. After raising the seatpost I do admit the creak went away, but after 30 miles I started having knee pain in my right knee making for an unpleasant ride. I went ahead and lowered the seat post soon after adjustment the creak sound appeared. Next day, took the SLK FSA post to the bike shop had them cut the post to my needed height after I was re fitted on my bike and no more creak!!! Also no more knee pain from raised the post being too high .Keep in mind I’m about 5’8 on a 54frame. The seat post was 350mm length .

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I do exactly this to the carbon bike almost every week just to check when I hear something even resembling a possible creak... well, that is if you ignore that I actually do something similar but even more stressful for the bike every single day; every time I take a corner fast in the woods and feel the tyres losing grip.

So far checking out creaks this way has led me to tighten the BB once and to tighten the crank arms once. However usually it's actually a seat post related creak (sometimes still heard when doing the above). A quick clean and some mounting paste sorts out the post.

If this procedure actually breaks your frame or something, then be happy, very happy. You avoided a serious injury.